# NUnit tests failed with FLuentValidation in ONion Architecture

Tags: asp.net-core, nunit, fluentvalidation, fluent-assertions, onion-architecture

Im trying to implement nunit tests with fluentvalidations, but it shows me a failed test and the message: `FluentValidation.AsyncValidatorInvokedSynchronouslyException : Validator "AddVehicleCommandValidator" contains asynchronous rules but was invoked synchronously. Please call ValidateAsync rather than Validate.`

In my test class I have a test method:

```cs
[Test]
public async Task ShouldRequireUniqueId()
{
    var vehicle = await SendAsync(new AddVehicleCommand
    {
        Vehicle = new VehicleDto
        {
            Maker = "BMW",
            Model = "M4",
            UniqueId = "C1"
        }
    });

    await SendAsync(new AddVehicleCommand
    {
        Vehicle = new VehicleDto
        {
            Maker = "BMW",
            Model = "M4",
            UniqueId = "C2"
        }
    });

    var command = new AddVehicleCommand
    {
        Vehicle = new VehicleDto
        {
            Maker = "BMW",
            Model = "M4",
            UniqueId = vehicle.Data.UniqueId
        }
    };

    var exception = FluentActions.Invoking(() => SendAsync(command))
        .Should().ThrowAsync<ValidationException>();
}
```

Method `SendAsync` is a generic method for using MediatR and IPipelineBehavior:

```cs
public static async Task<TResponse> SendAsync<TResponse>(IRequest<TResponse> request)
{
    using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();

    var mediator = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMediator>();

    return await mediator.Send(request);
}
```

also I setup nessery things for registering services at onetimesetup method:

```cs
[OneTimeSetUp]
public static void RunBeforeAnyTests()
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    var startup = new Startup(_configuration);
    startup.ConfigureServices(services);
    services.AddSingleton(Mock.Of<IWebHostEnvironment>(w => w.ApplicationName == "VehicleReservation.WebApi" && w.EnvironmentName == "Development"));
    _scopeFactory = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
    //_checkpoint = new Checkpoint();
}
```

So why this test fails? Tnx

**UPDATE#1:**

```
[Test]
        public async Task ShouldRequireUniqueId()
        {
            var vehicle = await SendAsync(new AddVehicleCommand
            {
                Vehicle = new VehicleDto
                {
                    Maker = "BMW",
                    Model = "M4",
                    UniqueId = "C1"
                }
            });

            await SendAsync(new AddVehicleCommand
            {
                Vehicle = new VehicleDto
                {
                    Maker = "BMW",
                    Model = "M4",
                    UniqueId = "C2"
                }
            });

            var command = new AddVehicleCommand
            {
                Vehicle = new VehicleDto
                {
                    Maker = "BMW",
                    Model = "M4",
                    UniqueId = vehicle.Data.UniqueId
                }
            };

            var exception = await FluentActions.Awaiting(() => SendAsync(command))
                .Should().ThrowAsync<ValidationException>();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you describes an asynchronous validator is synchronously invoked. See https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/async.html
So somewhere in your code you're blocking the validation.

`FluentActions.Invoke` takes an `Action`/`Func<T>`.

For async execution, use `Awaiting`

```cs
await FluentActions.Awaiting(() => SendAsync(command))
    .Should().ThrowAsync<ValidationException>();
```

Comment: please check my update#1. It has still the same error.

Comment: What happens if you run `SendAsync(command)` without using Fluent Assertions? If that pass then please add a complete minimal example that I we can post into an IDE and run.